# Remove encryption setup on a lvm/luks partition

Tags: linux, partitioning, encryption, lvm, luks

On my linux machine, I have setup disk encryption using lvm/luks. However later I delete one of the partition and format it to NTFS in order to use it on Windows (as I have dual boot linux/win10).

There is no problem so far except that I have repeated errors during boot which says

```
"systemd-cryptsetup[1458]: crypt_load() failed on device /dev/disk/by-id/ata-ST1000NM124-1EJ264_W722DT5A-part9.
systemd-cryptsetup[1458]: Failed to activate: Invalid argument"
```

How can I stop the system from trying to find the partition I have already reformatted so to get rid of this error?

The error doesn't prevent my system from booting at the moment though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the nonexistent device from `/etc/crypttab`.  The file needs root permissions to edit.

If doing the above doesn't fix your problem, it's possible that the decryption attempt is occurring in the initramfs.  All you have to do in this case is regenerate your initramfs.

In Debian/Ubuntu, run this command to regenerate the initramfs for the current kernel:

```
update-initramfs -uv
```

CentOS/Fedora:

```
dracut -fv
```

Arch Linux:

```
mkinitcpio -v -p linux
```

Comment: I edited the /etc/crypttab and the error was gone ! Much thanks!